# python: condense conditional OR that check several variables equal to a common value

Tags: python, python-3.x, conditional-statements

Say I want to condense the following line of code:

```
if a == 10 or b == 10 or sum == 10 or diff == 10:
    # do something
```

Is there a way to condense all of these ors to point to a single value?

Something like:

```
if (a or b or sum or diff) == 10:
    # do something
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flip it around

`if 10 in {a, b, sum, diff}` should work

To generalize for more values use this:

`if {val1, val2, val3} & {a, b, sum, diff}`

Comment: TypeError: set expected at most 1 arguments, got 4

Comment: Sorry about that. Fixed

Comment: Thank you that does work. I had put set() it should just be {}. Point awarded

Comment: Don't forget to accept one of the answers. Also look at @linusg answer since that might generalize better

Comment: This should be at the top. I like how it uses set intersection as a means for generalization. Haven't time it, but set-search should be better than list/tuple search. (It wouldn't make any difference for this use case any way though)

Comment: Just to be clear is this checking if ANY 'val' in the set on the left matches ANY 'var' in the set on the right? This is really amazing.

Comment: You create two sets one with the vals you are looking for and one with the vals you have and then you do a set intersection between them and check if the resulting set is empty. This will check if any of the vals in the left is included in the vals on the right

Answer (score 3):

```
if 10 in [a, b, sum, diff]:
```

However, note that this works only for a *single* common value.  If you have two values to compare against four different variables, you don't get the "distributive law" so easily implemented.

Comment: Could you write if (10 or 5) in [...]?

Comment: No you can not do this

Comment: @vampiire Check my answer for something that generalizes to more values.

Comment: Whoa thank you. I didn't know & was even used in python. Learned three things from you today! I will award solution checkmark in 6 minutes it won't let me do it any sooner. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

It's not much shorter, but I'd use the built-in [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

```
any(val == x for val in (a, b, c))
```

In your case:

```
if any(val == 10 for val in (a, b, sum, diff)):
    # do something
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yours is a bit more verbose. Is there a reason to use this approach vs what Giannis or Prude suggested? Not belittling your answer just want to learn why one may be more useful than the other.

Comment: All the answers have their pros and cons ;)
No, there's no special reason for this, just came to my mind. You can also do more advanced things with this, like adding something to `val` or if clause a special value.